# Can I treat the sum of the coefficients of a variable in the Error Correction Model as total short-run effects?

Tags: vector-error-correction-model, ecm

I am working on a project that uses ECM model to inspect the short-run dynamics of money supply (m(t)) to loans (l(t)) since both variables are I(1). Excluding the error correction term, is it appropriate to aggregate the coefficients for l(t) to obtain its overall short-run effects? i.e. for al(t-2)+bl(t-1)+cl(t), I obtain total short-run coefficient by a+b+c. I am not sure if this is an appropriate way to follow.

Please, I really need technical assistance from experts here.

Comment: How do you define the notion of *total short-run effects*?

Comment: @RichardHardy, good question. For the total short-run effects, I refer to the short-run dynamics denoted by the lags of the independent and dependent variables given in the right-hand-side of the ECM equation. Specially in my case, I refer to summing the total coefficients of loan to gather its over short-run effect. I am not sure, I could be wrong. I'd appreciate your corrections and assistance.

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. See, if you define the total short-run effects as the sum of individual lags, then your approach is correct by definition and the answer to your question is obviously a yes. If you are asking whether your approach is correct, you must be referring to some known definition that is formulated differently and then need to find out whether the two definitions actually match.

Comment: @RichardHardy. Thank you, for confirming this. Previously, I used to think that the short-run dynamics should be interpreted individually that's why I inquired if aggregating them would be appropriate. There is no other definition that I intend in this question as it might be implied that I wanted to verify.